# How to prove this problem is NP-Complete

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, np-complete

Give a graph G(V, E) and two integers X, Y:
Problem: Is there a subset of vertices V' in V in the size of X
Where in this subset there are at least Y edges?
The problem is to show it is NP-Complete.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Clique is a subproblem of your one and is known to be NP-complete. Thus, your problem is NP-hard. To show that it is NP-complete, simply show that it lies in NP.

Regarding the comments, here a little edit:
If $V'$ is a set with $X$ vertices, then $V'$ is a complete subgraph (i.e. a clique), if and only if $V'$ contains ... edges. I think you are able to figure out the missing number yourself: How many edges does a complete graph have, if you know the number of vertices?

Comment: That's what I thought but I'm struggling on how to do the reduction regarding the edges. I think this called the "Exact Graph" problem.

Comment: Which reduction? There is no real reduction to be done if you know that Clique is NP-complete. A proof for that fact can be found in (almost) every textbook on the topic or on the Internet...

Comment: The "reduction" is explaining that the Clique is a subproblem of my problem. The clique problem is a little different than this one because here there's no rule that between EVERY 2 vertexes there's an edge.

Comment: regarding the last edit: It means y must be: y >= x(x-1)/2 if I'm correct..

Comment: Sounds good, yes.